# Make command doesn't execute but Makefile.am existed

Tags: command-line, 16.04, make

I have been using Ubuntu (16.04) for only a week at most and I am still learning (with lots of confusion) on using the terminal.

So right now I am following a tutorial for TensorFlow YOLO tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npZ-8Nj1YwY), and I get it right until the tutor type `make` command in the terminal (minute 7:39) and it started to execute or do something.

But when I did it (type `make` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>), it gives out this error.

[image: The error after pressing Enter]

Thus, I went and check if there is any Makefile in the directory, and there is.

[image: Makefile exist in the directory]

Therefore, how do I execute the `make` command in the terminal? Is there anything that I did wrong or didn't do specifically ? Or is it because he did it on Raspberry Pi and I did it on Ubuntu (but then why I could follow until the minute 7:39 without a problem) ?

Comment: Makefile.am is not the same as Makefile. Please run `./configure` again and tell us the last 5 lines. We suspect that it does *not* include: `config.status: creating Makefile`

Comment: I did it like you said, run ./configure again, and try again. It worked.

What actually happened? I don't understand what changed?

Also, before I tried again, there is this (venv) in the terminal, what does that mean?

Comment: I haven't any idea what (venv) specifies; however, I'm glad it's working now as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makefile.am is not the same as Makefile. Please run `./configure` again and check if the last several lines of output include: `config.status: creating Makefile` If not, there are errors or, most likely, missing dependencies. Correct those faults and try `./configure` again. It may take several tries.

When it ends successfully in `config.status: creating Makefile`, you may proceed to `make` and, presumably, `sudo make install`.